# Calculating average time between revisits into a pixel in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, time, spatio-temporal-data

To determine the revisit rate of elephants into specific areas (several pixels across a map) I am looking at calculating the average time between visits into each specific pixel.

I have a bunch of GPS points with both the date and time associated with each point. I used the spatial join tool to associate each point with the pixel it is in, so I have a table with one row representing a GPS point, and each row contains the date, time and a number which represents the pixel.

Is there a tool (or combination of tools) within ArcGIS Pro that can calculate the average time between visits into a pixel for me?

I have looked at time series smoothing tools and other time clustering/mining tools but they all seem to work on the values associated with the dates/times rather than the actual dates/times itself.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is mixing terminology and very unclear what you have done. The Spatial Join tool works with vector data, but you keep referring to a pixel which is a raster data structure. When you say "pixel" you may or may not actually referring to a polygon dataset which is in a grid like structure, often referred to as a fishnet. A good question on GIS SE should always include images of your data so that it's crystal clear what you are talking about.

Also, what you mean by an "average time" is not clear. Say you have 3 gps points in a cell and lets say for argument sake they have time stamps on 01:00, 12:00, 15:00, all on the same day, you may or may not actually mean *range*, because a GPS is a single point in time not an entry or exit of the cell which would have given you an amount of time within the cell.

If you want range then explore the summary statistics tool, your case field parameter would be your cell ID and you can extract the date range.

I would suggest you edit your question, include some images, what your input data is and what you want.